# Ruby CSV how to return nil instead of undefined method error?

Tags: ruby, csv, undefined, null

```
 csv_content = CSV.generate do |csv|
      csv << [
        "Bus number",
        "Bus name",
        "Bus Driver Name",
      ]

      @buses.each do |bus|
        csv << [
          bus.number,
          bus.name,
          bus.driver.name
        ]
        end
    end
```

Here is a code snippet to generate csv content,
however, bus.driver.name will throw nil class error if bus.driver is nil. 
How can i return nil instead?
How can we do it  more elegant?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Rails (or Active Support):

```
bus.driver.try(:name)
```

If not, just add it yourself:

```
class Object
  alias :try :send
end
class NilClass
  def try(method); end
end
```